# How to prevent duplicate sprites when entering fullscreen mode on jwplayer

Tags: fullscreen, jwplayer

I've created custom social plugin for jwplayer5 with actionscript3 but when entering fullscreen myClip Sprite doubles. How can I prevent this? I have an  event for full screen mode and I tried to change the x and y positions depending on screen resolution but it doesn't help. I still see two myClip sprites as in this picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYRCw.jpg).

Also after I leave fullscreen doubled sprite leaves on the player and if I eneter again in fullscreen then i see 3 sprites. It multiplies after each fullscreen.

Here is my code for creating myclip sprite

```
private function shareBar():void {

        myClip = new Sprite();
        myClip.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0.2);
        myClip.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 45, this.pHeight);
        myClip.graphics.endFill();
        myClip.x = this.pWidth;
        addChild(myClip);

        var _player:Stage = RootReference.stage;
        _player.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, this.mOver);
        _player.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, onMouseLeave);
        _player.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
        stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN,fullscreenCall);

        var fb:SimpleButton = new FBbtn();
        fb.name = "fb";
        fb.y = 5;
        fb.x = 5;
        myClip.addChild(fb);
        var tw:SimpleButton = new TWbtn();
        tw.name = "tw";
        tw.x = 5;
        tw.y = 45;
        myClip.addChild(tw);
        var gp:SimpleButton = new Gbtn();
        gp.name = "gp";
        gp.x = 5;
        gp.y = 85;
        myClip.addChild(gp);
        myClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.btnClick);
    }
```

Comment: Are you laying out the plugin inside of the resize function? "public function resize(wid:Number, hei:Number):void {" You pretty much should always do that.

Comment: I solved it i had used sprites creation code in resize function so that's why it doubled each time i resize the window...

Comment: Glad you got it working.